# Creating a multipage at runtime crashes excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to create and Multipage object in Excels VBA at runtime.
This shouldn't be a problem, normally.

_**First, the code:**

```
Set objMPage = UI.frmOutput.Controls.Add( _
                    "Forms.Multipage.1", _
                    "mpgInteractions", _
                    False)
```

_**What are those objects?**

UI is a userform,
frmOutput is a Frame

_**What goes wrong?**
The code as stated above results in excel crushing for unknown reasons.
If, however, the Multipage is created just on the Userform, no error occurs. So, this code:

```
Set objMPage = UI.Controls.Add( _
                    "Forms.Multipage.1", _
                    "mpgInteractions", _
                    False)
```

works.

Sadly, I need the Multipage inside the Frame and hope someone can help me with this issue.

Comment: Works for me. Of course, `False` needs to be changed to true if you want to see the multipage.

Answer (score 4):

Like I mentioned it works for me.

This is the code that I tried.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim objMPage As MultiPage

    Set objMPage = frmOutput.Controls.Add( _
                    "Forms.Multipage.1", _
                    "mpgInteractions", _
                    True)

End Sub
```

and this is the output

[image]

Comment: + 1 I know you have Excel 2010. :p This works in Excel 2007 as well.

Comment: lol@PradeepKumar: I already tested that in Excel 2007 and 2010. Haven't tested it in Excel 2003/2011/2013. But I guess it should work...

Comment: Thanks, for your help. If I'm not mistaken, you simply left out the reference to the Userform (namely "UI" in my example).